# Counting group size in a 2d array recursively

Tags: java

I'm trying to count the total group size from a inputted point. The user will enter a point (row, col) and for a group like:

```
__XX
__X_
```

would return 3 because it has 3 X's. So I have almost figured this out, but my issue is that it is not counting some of the X's in certain situations. For example:

```
_XX
XXX
```

If I were to call this method on the top left most X then it would return 4 (it doesn't count the bottom left most X, but if I called this on the bottom left most X it will return 5. Another example:

```
__XX
__XX
__XX
__XX
___X
__X_
```

Now, this should return 9 because that 10th X is diagonal to the others and would not be included.

Here is my method:

```
public int sizeGroup(int row, int col) {
    if (!board[row][col]) {
        // the point entered is not at a valid group
        return counter;
    } else if (first) {
        rowInitial = row;
        colInitial = col;
        first = false;
        return sizeGroup(row, col);
    } else {
        if (!visited[row][col]) {
            counter++;
        }
        visited[row][col] = true;

        if (row < board.length - 1 && board[row + 1][col] && !visited[row + 1][col]) {
            return sizeGroup(row + 1, col);
        } else if (row > 0 && board[row - 1][col] && !visited[row - 1][col]) {
            return sizeGroup(row - 1, col);
        } else if (col < board[0].length - 1 && board[row][col + 1] && !visited[row][col + 1]) {
            return sizeGroup(row, col + 1);
        } else if (col > 0 && board[row][col - 1] && !visited[row][col - 1]) {
            return sizeGroup(row, col - 1);
        } else if (isVisitedAround(row,col)) {
            return sizeGroup(rowInitial, colInitial);
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
private boolean isVisitedAround(int row, int col) {
    if (row < board.length - 1 && visited[row + 1][col] && row > 0 && visited[row - 1][col]
            && col < board[0].length - 1 && visited[row][col + 1] && col > 0 && visited[row][col + 1]) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your goal here? Given a point, count the X under the point and all (cardinally? diagonally?) adjacent X's recursively?

Comment: The whole group of X's that are connected, but not counting diagonal